# LabelFor behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I just fixed a bug in my code but I don't understand why this was happening. 
I have a `LabelFor(u => u.SomeName, "Select a value")`. `SomeName` is an enum value and the control is a radio button group. When I click on the `label` it changes the radio button group's value to the first radio button which would also be the default value for that enum.

When I changed all of my `LabelFor`s to `Label` I don't have the issue so the bug is fixed there but I really want to understand this.

Can anyone tell me why is it that clicking a `LabelFor` label will change my radio button value?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble trying to filter out the ASP in this question, but a label needs to be bound to a single form control (such as a radio button) and not multiple form controls (such as a group of radio buttons) … and you need one label per radio button. Use a fieldset with a legend to describe the radio buttons as a group.

Comment: @Quentin - That was exactly my fail. I didn't understand what the for attribute really does.. I do now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit more research I understand it now but I'm not going to delete this just in case anybody else comes across this.

The labelfor makes a `<label for='element'>` when that label is clicked it will also select the control that it is bound to.

In this case I am selecting the default value for the enum that is bound to the label.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to your own question, and for leaving that question for future visitors. As a side note, though, it might be worth looking at the [Stack Overflow Mark-Down help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), for tips on how to format.